# How to pass array from php to ajax success function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am developing a web app. I am retrieving data from the database and storing it to an array using the `$row = mysqli_fetch_array()`. The problem is, that this array is supposed to go to `ajax` using `echo json_encode($array)` but I don't know how to receive it from ajax success function, by the way, I am using the `jQuery.parseJSON()`. After that, I am going to append the values from that array to an `<option>` element.

get_AssetModel.php:

```
$sqlGetAssetModels = "select * from tblbrands where brand_name like '$phpGetAssetModels'";
//$array = array();
$models = array();

if ($result = mysqli_query($cn, $sqlGetAssetModels)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $models[] = $row[3];
    }
} else {

}

echo json_encode($models);
```

javascript file who's gonna receive the array:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "inventory/get_AssetModel.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: chAssBrand,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            var node = document.createElement("option");
            var textnode = document.createTextNode(data.0);
            node.appendChild(textnode);
            document.getElementById("txtInvModel").appendChild(node);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            swal("Error!", textStatus, "error");
        }
    });
```

OR IS THEIR OTHER WAY?

Comment: Could you please share how you represent your data in the response block. Want to know `jQuery.parseJSON(data);` data. It's an array with objects? or only an array of values.

Comment: It's an array of values only. I was thinking of objects with named indexes but I think it's not gonna work.

Comment: What doesn't work? Use your browser's DevTools/Network tab to see the results returned. Or in your `success` function use `console.table(data)` to print the data used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your `data` may look like the below example:

```js
var data = ["Anthony", "Jhake", "Ravelo", "Antigro"];

data.forEach(function(value, index) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = value;
  option.value = index;
  var select = document.getElementById("txtInvModel");
  select.appendChild(option);
});
```

```html
<select name="txtInvModel" id="txtInvModel">
  <option value="">Select one</option>
</select>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for this great idea. I'm gonna try this sir. But, how about retrieving the data from my database should I make changes too from the way I construct my code in $models[] = $row[3]?

Comment: If the $row[3] contains a single set of context then you should not have to do anything over there.